# Basic: displaying an image using XML and XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Already looked through StackOverflow and other sites for this answer.

Most questions involve code I am not using, and I am looking for an answer to a simpler form of the question. I want and answer for the most basic, vanilla, method of doing this sort of thing. There is no more to the two files than I have posted here. All file, xml, xsl, and the image are all in the same directory.

my XML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="image_experiment.xsl"?>

<root>
   <my_content>

      <p>IMAGE FOR TESTING XML ONLY</p>
      <image>
          sizes_1-6.gif
      </image>

    </my_content>
</root>
```

my XSL file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="root">

    <xsl:template match="image">
        <img src="{@image}"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>


   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSLT is erroneous in two ways:

- Nesting templates is prohibited
- Your XPath expression does not match the node you want, because
  you select `image/@image`(attribute-node) instead of the correct `image/text()`(text-value-node).

So fixing both you'll get

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/root">     
  <html>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="image">
  <img src="{normalize-space(text())}"/>     <!-- remove leading and trailing spaces as well -->
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see I also added a minimum HTML around that `img`-tag.

Comment: While this worked nicely, it is not exactly what I want. It did get my image displayed and that gave me some confidence to keep studying and a direction to go. I have learned that I need to learn more about xslt, such as the <xsl:element> and <xsl:attribute> and some of the parameters that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final solution which works nicely - except it prints the name of the image file next to the image. Still researching to find out how to prevent that.

Sample XML tag

```
<image-center>
    size_cat_1-6.jpg
</image-center>

<image-left>
    size_cat_7-10.gif
</image-left>

<image-right>
    size_cat_8-10.gif
</image-right>
```

The XSLT to display the actual image in the browser

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


<xsl:template match="image-center">
    <img src="{.}"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="image-left">
    <img src="{.}"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="image-right">
    <img src="{.}"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```